# kde-full and unistalling some of its packages

Tags: apt, kde

I installed KDE using `kde-full` - so far so good. But when I try to unistall some of its app wich is not so neceseary to me (like marble or kalgebra), apt-get remove will show me

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  knetwalk kpat kalzium-data kdepim kolf xscreensaver-gl
  plasma-desktopthemes-artwork ksystemlog libsdl-ttf2.0-0 krdc krfb kdesdk
  kscd kppp libopenbabel4 libanalitzagui4abi1 kshisen kdeartwork-style
  kmahjongg kopete-message-indicator kcharselect kanagram kde-baseapps
  libksane0 cervisia kdeartwork-theme-window knode kblocks katomic kruler
  plasma-containments-addons svgpart ktux kdegraphics-thumbnailers klettres
  kajongg kgoldrunner libknewstuff2-4 kgeography pkg-kde-tools xplanet
  ksnapshot plasma-wallpapers-addons translate-toolkit libkexiv2-data
  libcfitsio3 libkipi8 libkipi-data kaccessible kblackbox libotr2 bomber
  kiriki libgrantlee-gui0 kde-standard libsdl-mixer1.2 libglew1.5 kstars
  ttf-dustin kbruch gwenview advancecomp libmarblewidget13 python-levenshtein
  printer-applet kfilereplace libkggznet4 umbrello kcalc kdeplasma-addons
  libavogadro1 libkggzmod4 parley konsolekalendar kontact kimagemapeditor
  libportmidi0 kmplot kdiamond kalzium libindi-data ksirk ksquares klinkstatus
  klickety libkcddb4 libkateinterfaces4 libgadu3 kalarm blogilo kdewebdev
  kwrite libkeduvocdocument4 plasma-dataengines-addons libkdcraw-data kdegames
  amor marble-plugins kdeaccessibility rocs libboost-graph1.46.1
  libnova-0.12-2 ktouch kbreakout kbounce kfourinline libkdegames5a kdetoys
  python-avogadro ktimetracker akregator avogadro-data kollision
  kdegraphics-strigi-analyzer python-enchant python-qt4 kamera sweeper
  lokalize kwordquiz kde-plasma-desktop libanalitza4abi1 ktron bovo python-sip
  cvs kdenetwork libkggzgames4 libmikmod2 step python-vobject palapeli-data
  krosspython kuser dragonplayer kcolorchooser kreversi kdf python-qt4-sql
  plasma-widget-folderview kdegraphics-mobipocket kspaceduel libkrossui4 kig
  rdesktop ksudoku juk tasks-icons klines kstars-data libao4 lskat
  plasma-widgets-addons kgamma kde-config-cddb kommander libkopete4
  kdegames-card-data kubrick kgeography-data ksaneplugin kdeutils kjumpingcube
  kdegraphics khangman plasma-scriptengine-superkaramba libkexiv2-10
  libqtassistantclient4 kscreensaver marble kolourpaint4 libindi0 killbots
  kapman plasma-widget-lancelot fonts-dustin kde-plasma-netbook
  plasma-runners-addons vorbis-tools poxml parley-data libkmahjongglib4
  kpartloader kdesdk-kio-plugins cvsservice libksane-data kbattleship kdeadmin
  kdesdk-scripts kdegames-mahjongg-data kdemultimedia-kio-plugins filelight
  xplanet-images libkdcraw20 kopete kde-config-cron kdesdk-misc palapeli kate
  kapptemplate ktouch-data kdewallpapers kscreensaver-xsavers
  kdesdk-strigi-plugins marble-data kjots klettres-data kdeartwork-emoticons
  libktorrent3 kmines python-iniparse kget kalgebra-common
  system-config-printer-kde kremotecontrol kdenetwork-filesharing kgpg
  libboost-regex1.46.1 konquest kigo kdemultimedia kmousetool
  kdepim-strigi-plugins optipng libmsn0.3 libkdeedu-data kuiviewer kmag gnugo
  kdeedu-kvtml-data ktuberling kturtle ktimer python-kde4 kteatime kmix
  kdeartwork kmtrace plasma-widget-message-indicator libsmpeg0
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  kalgebra kde-full kdeedu
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
After this operation, 497 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

Now that would unistall some needed package for kde as well. How to prevent it and unistall realy only what I want to uninstall? I don't believe that all of these packages are there only because of kalgenra.